# Online spaces, communities, or channels for professional and academic linguists?

Tags: discussion

I have lately been thinking about finding online forums or networks but on a way more professional level, for a topic.

Apart from a Stack Exchange site like Math Overflow, so far I only know of professional associations. There are good ones, like the Association for Computational Linguistics and so on.

What I don’t know is if those associations have “modernized” a bit by trying to support online communities with common modern software tools and platforms, such as a Discord server, a forum-type site like Stack Overflow or Discourse, or even just an active and helpful email group.

Are there?

Comment: Follow [The Linguist List](https://linguistlist.org/) for a while and you'll see what's going on.